# How to get an external entity from another rest api without rewriting it in yout aplication?

Tags: spring, rest, notifications, entity

This may be a rookie question, still a simple one. I am building a notification rest-api service with spring boot, but at some point i would need to utilize an entity from an remote spring boot rest-api in order to create a notificacion entity. You can get a remote external entity through RestTemplate or WebClient apis, but in that case you still would have to have acces to the entity class you are trying to get acces to. My question is, is there a way for me to ger acces to an remote entity through a request method, and access that entity's attributes, without having to rewrite in my api (or have in my classpath) the entity class i want to get and its service and repository classes.
Thank you very much in advance, any comments welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no, you can't (to my knowledge). The response you get from api is simply some structured text (I mean json), so to be able to use it as an entity, you have to create one. In Spring you could use i.e. Jackson's ObjectMapper.

Comment: i'm not very well versed on jackson mapper, but, in that case, it means that i could at least get an entity's property without having the entity itself, wright?

Comment: If your 'receiver' is a SpringBoot api, you can just model the same class (a POJO) and expect it as a response (@ResponseBody) / model it yourself from received json (with the use of Jackson).